# Netbeans 6.8 on Ubuntu 10.04: I add php to netbeans and when I type gksu netbeans its open netbeans without php editor

Tags: linux, ubuntu, netbeans

Netbeans 6.8 Ubuntu 10.04: I add php to netbeans and when I type **$ gksu netbeans** its open netbeans without php editor.
Only when I type **$ sudo netbeans** its open it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What? Running `sudo netbeans` opens NetBeans with the root user. You should simply start it with `netbeans` or with the icon. No need for root.

Comment: You didnt explain why its happen, I know that I can also open with icon.
thanks

Comment: gksu uses your user with root access. Its a "graphical sudo". So basically its your user, not the "root". If you use "sudo" , you will get the "root" account launch it. (So if you use gksu, it'll save the stuff into your folder, 'sudo' saves it into /root/)